# interfaces and generalisation in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have four entities (models) in TypeScript as follows:

Base class/model:

```
export interface BaseClass {
  id: string;
  entityId: string;
  entityName: string;
}
```

Child Class 1:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base-class';

export interface ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
  commentId: string;
  authorName: string;
}
```

Child Class 2:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base-class';

export interface ChildClass2 extends BaseClass {
  authorName: string;
}
```

Child Class 3:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base-class';

export interface ChildClass3 extends BaseClass {
  operationType: string;
}
```

In my component, how can I achieve generalisation just like we have in Java.

For ex: Have an object named,

```
public models: BaseClass[] = [];
```

How can I have different types of objects like `ChildClass1`, `ChildClass2`, `ChildClass3` present in the models objects above.

**EDIT:**

The following is a screenshot that shows the error in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Comment: You can. Just get or create instances of any of those interfaces, and push them to the array. What did you try? What's the concrete problem you faced?

Comment: @JBNizet: Please look at my recent edit.

Comment: @JBNizet Any pointers?

Comment: Can you include the code you're having trouble with as code and [not as a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?  And the text of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  The problem you are probably having is that when you use a "fresh" object literal (that is, one that hasn't already been assigned to some variable) and assign it to a variable of a specified type, TypeScript uses [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to warn you if you are adding unexpected properties.  Types in TypeScript are normally treated as open/extendable/generalizable, but in this one instance they are treated as closed/[exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), because it's *often* an error to do this.

```
const excessPropertyErrors: BaseClass[] = [
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" },
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" },
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" }
]; // error! excess property checks are biting us
```

So, how can we prevent this from happening to us?  All sorts of ways, in fact.

---

One is to explicitly mention the subclasses we expect.  The type `BaseClass` and `BaseClass | ChildClass1 | ChildClass2 | ChildClass3` are structurally identical, but they differ by how they see "extra" properties:

```
const explicitlyMentionSubclasses: 
 Array<BaseClass | ChildClass1 | ChildClass2 | ChildClass3> = [
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" },
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" },
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" }
]; // okay
```

That would still throw an excess property error if you misspell `operationType`, so you might want to mention the types in some way.  Still, having the type of your variable carry around the subclasses is kind of limiting.

---

Another way to do this is to assign the fresh object literal to variables annotated with the specific subclass type you care about, and then put those variables in your array:

```
const childClass1: ChildClass1 = 
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" };
const childClass2: ChildClass2 = 
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" };
const childClass3: ChildClass3 = 
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" };
const individualElements: BaseClass[] = [childClass1, childClass2, childClass3]; // okay
```

That's one of the safest ways you can do this, since each variable `childClass1`, `childClass2` and `childClass3` will be constrained and excess-property-checked to the relevant subclass.

---

Another way you can do this is to completely turn off excess property checks by having the object literals no longer be "fresh". First, assign the array to an unannotated variable; the type will be inferred by the compiler.  Then, assign the inferred-type variable to a `BaseClass[]` variable:

```
const completelyInferred = [
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" },
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" },
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" }
];
const noLongerFresh: BaseClass[] = twoStepProcess1; // okay
```

That works, but keep in mind that there will be absolutely no checking of anything except the `BaseClass` members.  If you make `operationType` a number, it will still be accepted.

---

You could decide that you want `BaseClass` never to have excess property checks ever.  One way to turn that completely off is to define a `BaseClass` extension which explicitly allows any excess properties of any type:

```
interface BaseClassWithUnknownExtraProperties extends BaseClass {
  [k: string]: unknown;  // add index signature
}
const indexSignature: BaseClassWithUnknownExtraProperties[] = [
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" },
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" },
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" }
]; // okay
```

---

Finally, you might want to use a helper function to accept extensions of `BaseClass` (which turns off excess property checking):

```
const asBaseClassArray = <T extends BaseClass>(arr: T[]) => arr;
const usingHelperFunction: BaseClass[] = asBaseClassArray([
  { id: "a", entityId: "b", entityName: "c", commentId: "d", authorName: "e" },
  { id: "f", entityId: "g", entityName: "h", authorName: "i" },
  { id: "j", entityId: "k", entityName: "l", operationType: "m" }
]); // okay
```

---

Hope one of those ways gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIBtMbIDeAUMssACYBcyGYUoA5gNxnITjBgCeAkjToNmbcpzDceAOTgBbCLXqMQrEgF8SJUJFiIU2ABbBclPAQCMHAB6QQlQuixmMhUuQQB7WfPADFwlVFkOABXMAMPKBl5f2VVDS1waHgkZENjU3wXACZrW3s0TBws13ZQ8MjohSE4tgTtZL00oxNnDABmPM4Cx2KCYnYPAAdoOAkPEAAVHhHYkXVNTxB6ayQXAAUoYeheAFEoLagMWl62gG0AXWQAXmQz9iIKQQAiOGeAGg4uXj9kZ4AjD5fCS8Kq0Z4IIGebziX7PShA8oRKJyarPCDPZBqd4PJ7gmBA8SSOFMQnfaSo8EGRFhZFgv7ATHY3FUcEAKzJIP4LwA1pzJPTnrggdsoGNgBNprM-rImSQLixkAB6JUcA6RACEqwgLmQQy2IygvGQCAMEAQPMIcCgKH+3GYyBCGEWExWECsQ1wwAQ3FwPAAskSJgBlEL-BAlHW0MgAQQOcB4AB5TiVkAAfZoZNqWDPpVolXK5lqZAjtAB8NzuLJeb0+RJ+L0BdfJgshn2hPjAcIRnyRlUpfwxWJx5EerL+BObXJJ-NBA+e1N7tP7MQZTJHxDxfw5U+JvNnFNXQpFhvFkpmaNlWPlipVyA8PITLuWYBNxeztDzJZclluY5rB5wk2wICvObYml4nbdjSFQokeQ5qGwSwrKaWYFp+74FpW-74oBLykruc5HouwTLnBaKMliSGuq+qH5qWGFoaW2Fbs8O4gQ24J8oRh5osKnyimeUwXuCV6ISQyGvqAlDAAAblQIRwLguy4BAnbHIUTglJclZnHR34YOY7aYQQ2TGUxLjtAqyqqg+T4STRyBgAA7h4waQEMmweGshm6dW4K1hx3LgsB9a8eC4EdrCLw9qRsGCghG44ROeHggRQWCiRfbkeClHMqOrHsWFcLcRl878fep7jMJ0rPGJN4OS+Tmue5ECeVsPnZCcRTnFctwuW5HleT55i3rZj48JoDS6KkKYEAA6twBgAKogDyIAeM5IC7DYYpeYaEg6l0dgOD1qZuHcPJzCoFy0CEa0bVtdSNSs0nusGwBMCAYwhDa3VaQtS2retm3bbtcD7TswA6jptz3AV46vKlfyhS2YFQpB0XgrF2UJeu-kpTxM48ZlMF0vOeVJYVyPPKVYWChVgnVVKl5ytZd52ZNL2vpgc0uHGYo8JWiaTMdPRnQQZYABTWlAtCTJcACUNwVrL1FNU6zAABIQLghoAGL3Qg1X-X0Liw8EGB8xgAsJlL8ObojgXFY2B6thjMK+DFZMrmiiUE88k5BcTZXET7OVrsOAdFeSJVu+VJ6jMzIkymzitjfeE0kEAA)

Comment: I'd use yet another option: `const array: BaseClass[] = [
  { ... } as ChildClass1,
  { ... } as ChildClass2,
  { ... } as ChildClass3
];`.